# include chunk of xsl

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a chunk of XSL code (along with Apache fop), that i want to reuse:

XSL version and schema used

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xml:lang="en"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
    exclude-result-prefixes="java"      
    xmlns:map="xalan://java.util.HashMap" extension-element-prefixes="map">
```

Chunk to reuse:

```
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="map:get($etiquetas,'datosMensajeLabel')" />

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" border-top-color="black"
            border-top-width="0.5pt" border-top-style="solid"
            background-color="grey">
            <fo:block text-align="start" color="white" font-size="12pt">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="map:put($etiquetas,'datosMensajeLabel','')" />
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="map:get($etiquetas,'datosMensajeLabel')" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:otherwhise>

        <fo:table-cell padding="2pt" background-color="grey">
            <fo:block text-align="start" color="white" font-size="12pt">
                
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="map:get($etiquetas,'datosMensajeLabel')" />
            </fo:block>
        </fo:table-cell>
    </xsl:otherwhise>
```

I tried so far:

1. Declare and use named **templates**: it fails since table-cell breaks the Apache fop schema where template is declared
2. Put that chunk of code in another file and use **import** or **include**: it's of no use as it's not used as a child of xsl:stylesheet

Comment: Maybe you could wrap it in an xsl:function in a separate file and include that?

Comment: @morsor the same error that using templates: fo:table-cell not allowed in that position

Comment: Your <xsl:when> element is closed - and <xsl:choose> does not allow anything but <xsl:when> or <xsl:otherwise>. Make the <xsl:when> wrap the xsl:fo code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error **fo:table-cell not allowed in that position** is that the preceding xsl:when element is closed and therefore not wrapping the <fo:table-cell> element.

xsl:choose only allows either xsl:when or xsl:otherwise as direct children and thus complains when it finds <fo:table-cell>.

Wrapping xsl:when around <fo:table-cell> should eliminate the error message.

By the way, you have misspelt xsl:otherwise

Comment: that was it, a copy-paste mistake. Works like a charm with a template and <xsl:call-template name="..."/>, thanks!